# Firebase Dynamic Link Classes not getting recognized in androidstudio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

[image]Why Firebase dynamic link could not be made , i just don't get the reason behind dynamic link not being detected .It says that what i will need to do is put the library 11.0.4 of firebase invites in gradle. But that is also not working since my android studio fails to recognize the following library. So i don't get the reason behind the bull-bulkshit done by Google Firebase.

```
DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
    .setLink(Uri.parse("https://example.com/"))
    .setDynamicLinkDomain("abc123.app.goo.gl")
    // Open links with this app on Android
    .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
    // Open links with com.example.ios on iOS
    .setIosParameters(new DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("com.example.ios").build())
    .buildDynamicLink();
```

This is my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

If anyone could help with that? Then please help with the fact that How to use Firebase Invite Api Sending intent with the other applications instead of being bounded by only Email and sms service?

Comment: what lib you have added in `build.gradle` for `firebase`?

Comment: +1, please paste in your build.gradle dependencies. Also ensure you have updated the "Google Repository" in the SDK manager.

Comment: @Shailesh, i have added 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.1'  and as i have already mentioned that i too tried to put firebase invite 11.0.4 but it's not being detected by android studio

Comment: @IanBarber this is the screenshot of my sdk manager

Comment: The Google repository is actually a package in the SDK tools , not an update site - can you check that is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i solved my issue by doing some updating and though in the so called automated world we are surrounded in, there are few things which we need to do them manually.
So go in the settings and reach to the sdk tools option  by searching in the settings dialog box.
After going there

STEP 2: Select the SDK tools and see there the google repository
    option

STEP 3: If it is not installed then please install it and if studio
    is showing you the update then too update it to lateset version

STEP 4:
Taadaaa...And now you are done
Now you can use firebase-invites-11.0.4 and thus you can use DynamicLinks class